# What does terminal / hyperterm display in the tab title? Is it possible to customize this?

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, hyperterm

I'm confused what data is being shown in my terminal tabs. The first part, `epzio` is obviously my username. But the second part, `@C02S60BBG8WP`, I have no idea.

*Note: I use zsh combined with oh-my-zsh for my shell.*

Is it possible to customize what is shown in the tab titles? I'd like to remove the `epzio@C02S60BBG8WP` part altogether and just display the current working directory.

Also, why do my tab titles turn blue for no apparent reason? I thought this was only supposed to happen when you had a specific process such as node running. As you can see in the screenshot below, the `tic-tac-toe` tab has turned blue even though nothing is happening in that tab.

**Update:** It seems that the solution might involve making changes to `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh`, but I'm not sure if these would get overridden when oh-my-zsh updates itself.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C02S60BBG8WP` is probably your hostname; check by typing `hostname`.

You can change the terminal title by printing an escape sequence like this:

```
echo -en "\033]0;New terminal title\a"
```

So this should change the title to your current working directory, `$PWD`, substituted by a single `~` if you're in `$HOME`:

```
echo -en "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably being overridden immediately afterwards by a command that is automatically invoked by your shell. In bash, this would be `PROMPT_COMMAND` which on my system looks like this:

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND 
__vte_prompt_command; printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
```

The [zsh equivalent](https://superuser.com/questions/735660/whats-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-prompt-command) seems to be to define a `precmd` hook:

```
precmd() { echo -en "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007" }
```

To make that permanent, you can just put it your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. `precmd() { echo -n -e "\033]0;$(basename "$PWD")\007" }` is what I eventually settled on, and I placed it at the bottom of `.zshrc`. The only additional thing I needed to do, since I'm using oh-my-zsh, was to uncomment `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"`

Comment: If you're using Oh-My-Zsh, don't forget to add the following option to your .zshrc file
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"